# OpenVX optical flow pyramids performance

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow, openvx

The question is about performance of OpenVX compared to the traditional OpenCV package. Do you know guys, which of them is faster in the calculation of optical flow pyramids? The function in OpenCV for this operation is following:
  cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid(nextFrame, nextPyr, winSize, maxLevel, true);
Who is faster?

Answer (score 1):

OpenVX is just a standard. You can compare performance of some OpenVX implementation. As far as I know, currently only sample implementation of the OpenVX standard (can be found on official Khronos site) is available publicly. This sample implementation doesn't use any optimizations, so I suppose it will be slower then OpenCV. To get real comparison you need to wait official production implementation of OpenVX standard from one of vendors.

Answer (score 0):

I tested openVX feature detection (harris corner detection) and tracking (LK optical flow Pyramid) on Jetson TX2 GPU and got algorithm runtime in the range of 2-5ms (based on the features in the video, in my case moving car was capturing features on the road).

I am not sure if OpenCV CUDA version can beat this.